# Rails 5.1+: Track how long a record is in a stage/status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, statistics, metrics, duration

For reporting purposes, I'm trying to track the amount of time a record is in a particular stage.

I have a typical `has_many :through`.

```
class Record < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :record_stages
  has_many :stages, through: :record_stages
end

class RecordStage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :stage
  belongs_to :record
end

class Stage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :record_stages
  has_many :records, through: :record_stages
end
```

This leads to a situation where a `record` has multiple `record_stages`, noting that a `record` can be in the same stage multiple times:

- record 1

  - record_stage 1
  - record_stage 2
  - record_stage 1
  - record_stage 3 (current)

**Question**

What I'm trying to solve is calculating how long the `record` spent in each of the `record_stages`?  If the record was in the same stage multiple times, I need them summed up for a total time in each stage.

I'm trying to figure out if there's some elegant way I can use timestamps on the `record_stage` to track how long it was in each stage.

The end result will be a tabular report table where I list each `record_stage` and the averages spent in each stage.  Note that a record may not ever be in all stages.

- record_stage 1: 4h
- record_stage 2: 2h
- record_stage 3: 7h

Comment: How do you figure out when a record is no longer in a stage (have you got a end time field in the database/model)?

Comment: The current stage for a record is the last `record_stage`.  What I'm trying to figure out is if I need to add a `left_stage_at:datetime` to the `record_stage` table or how should I track the "duration" of a particular stage.  For my purposes, a record leaves a stage when that stage is no longer the latest `record_stage` record.